# How do you integrate $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$, and what are non-integrable functions?

Tags: integration

I've had this question to integrate this function today in my exam.
$$e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$$
**Is this function one of a kind which are known as non-integrable functions?**

WolframAlpha offers a [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20e%5E%28-1/x%29) in terms of some exponential integral function $Ei(x)$

As some people in comments mentioned, this function 'is' integrable over many intervals e.g. $[1,2]$, how do you actually solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing non-integrable with [non-elementary?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral)

Comment: It is "non-integrable" in the sense that it does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions. It is integrable in the sense that the integral of it over most intervals does exists (e.g. over $[1,2]$).

Comment: Either the exam was in error or the question on the exam was something other than "Find the antiderivative of $e^{-1/x}$.

Comment: @Potato No, the question was simply "Integrate $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$", so I am not mistaken. I am asking a more general question here. As you say, if it is integrable over an interval e.g. $[1,2]$, how do you do it?

Comment: @Cheeku The exam must have had a typo then. There's not a nice antiderivative for that function. If you want the value of the integral over some interval, you would use numerical integration software like WolframAlpha. There isn't an elegant way to do it by hand.

Comment: @Potato No elegant way, but there must be a way. Can you give a hint where to search for it?

Comment: @Cheeku Well, you could do whatever algorithm the computer uses by hand. But it would take weeks.

Comment: You can use a simple quadrature to (approximately) integrate it.  ie: pick N points (say, 10) evenly spaced (because why not) evaluate the function at those points, multiply each by the size of your integration domain / N (to find the area of the rectangle), and then sum them all up.

Answer (score 1):

As $e^{-\frac 1 x}$ is continuous, it is integrable. But it has no elementary antiderivate, you can't state $\int e^{-\frac 1 x} d x$ in terms of elementary functions.

A non integrable function would be $\chi_{\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Q}$ on $[0,1]$ (at least Riemann integrable).